# Accessing array pointer in separate function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Say I have an array of n characters. 
I want to pass the amount, and a pointer to the array to a function, to check for the biggest value in the array. However, I'm unsure how to access the values from the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int *numbers, int size) {
  int temp = size;
  for (int i=0;i<temp;i++) {
   /*How do i access the array values?*/
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  int amount;
  int Array[amount];
    int *ptr;
  printf("Enter size of array:");
  scanf("%d",&amount);
  ptr = &Array[amount];

  for(int i=0;i<amount;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&Array[i]);
  }
  printf("Number 2 in array: %d",Array[1]);
  printf("\n calling function \n");
  max(ptr,amount);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `numbers[i]`

Comment: - but `&Array[amount]` gives you a reference to just beyond the array.

Comment: `int amount; int Array[amount];`is already wrong, you didn't initialize `amount` before using it to create an array

Comment: To beyond? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Drax `&Array[i]` gives you a point to the i'th element of the array.  If the array contains `amount` elements (so the valid indexes are `0`..`amount-1`), then `&Array[amount]` gives you a pointer to that invalid element just past the end.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems -- you don't set `amount` before using it to create `Array` so you get an undefined-size array, and `Array[amount]` is past the end of the array.  What you want is something more like:

```
  int amount;
  int *ptr;
  printf("Enter size of array:");
  scanf("%d",&amount);
  int Array[amount];
  ptr = Array;
```

and having `ptr` as a separate variable is not terribly useful -- you can just call `max(Array, amount)`